# Swift + Parse Logout Error

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I have an error when trying to kill user session when the logout button is pressed. Anybody have an idea where im going wrong? Thanks in advance
Here is the code

```
@IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

    PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock({ (error:NSError!) -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);

    })
```

Error: *'Cannot invoke 'logOutInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((NSError) -> Void)'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the type specifier `NSError!` from the param.

```
PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock({(error) -> Void in
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Works fine now :D

Comment: Why do we do this? Thanks!